# Regex Number Capture Without Percent Sign

Tags: regex, google-sheets

**Overall Goal**: I would like to be able to capture a positive or negative number that looks something like this: xxx.xxx

I am also using Google Sheets, so I cannot use any lookarounds

Example Criteria:

- `+123.123  --->  123.123`
- `+30%      --->  30`
- `+4%       --->  4`
- `-1%       --->  -1`
- `0         --->  0`
- `+12       --->  12`
- `-3        --->  -3`

**What I've Tried:**

The main regex I've been using is: `-?\d+.?\d*`. The problem with this one is that it also captures the percent signs, which I do not want. Percent signs seem to be considered part of the number.

I've also tried: `-?\d+.?\d+`. This one runs to the problem of not capturing single digit numbers.

Comment: I think you can use `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` matches any character (Google [uses](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)). You should escape it.

```
-?\d+\.?\d*
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thank you!